# Install Docker on Windows Server 2008

Tags: docker

How does one install docker for Windows Server 2008?

I only see support for Windows Server 2016:
https://www.docker.com/docker-windows-server

Answer (score 14):

**Docker for Windows** https://www.docker.com/docker-windows only works on **Windows 10 Pro/2016**.

[image]

For **all** other windows versions you must use **Docker Toolbox**
 https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/. A subtle but important difference.

Docker Toolbox comes with the ominous warning:

> **Legacy desktop solution**. Docker Toolbox is for older Mac and Windows systems that do not meet the requirements of Docker for Mac
>   and Docker for Windows. We recommend updating to the newer
>   applications, if possible.

So I guess this is not getting maintained anymore and may disappear.

Comment: I believe the links which you have mentioned in your answer, are for installing in windows 7, 10. It still does not tell us how to install for windows server 2008 and windows server 2012. This was what I meant to say.

Comment: Docker toolbox is for **all** other versions of windows. I've tested on 2008 (though not 2012).

Answer (score 4):

You can install it with "Docker Toolbox for Windows" from here: [Official Source](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/)

I had problem in installation but finally installed properly with these catches:

- Hyper V must be enabled (wasn't possible when I was trying in windows server hosted in another VM, had to switch)
- It was telling that virtualbox has error so it cannot continue :/ Solved it by uninstalling docker, virtualbox both, then removed all vbox* .dll files from c:\windows\system32\drivers folder. Afterwards when re-installed again, it worked.